# Image of form as global variable

Tags: c#

If you look at the restore eric button, you'll see I'm restoring his size back to 135. I would like to have his size restored back to the original size via a variable. I would like this variable to be declared when the form is first opened, so that it will always create a new original height & width when I change them in the form designer.

I tried to make the form_load public and declare the variables like this: int originalWidth = pictureEric.Width;

Then I try to call upon these variables in the restore void so I can restore them again.
However it keeps telling me the variables don't exist in the current context.

Any ideas?

```
public partial class formSouthPark : Form
{

    public formSouthPark()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void formSouthPark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Snow;
        int originalHeight = pictureEric.Height;
        int originalWidth = pictureEric.Width;
    }

    private void buttonRestoreEric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureEric.Height = originalHeight;
        pictureEric.Width = originalWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do some reading on variable scope.

Comment: You have to declare originalHeight and originalWidth as class variables. You are declaring them in the Load method so they are only accessible there. Declare them outside of the method but in the class, and then set them in the Load method.

Comment: +1, because -1 is unfair when you have other blatantly lazy posters, who can't be bothered to read a documentation or language specification, yet get tens or hundreds of upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some research on variable scope — Google is a good place to start. [This article on informIT](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609145&seqNum=4) also provides a pretty good explanation of how the whole scope idea works.

However, skipping the whole explanation (both for the sake of brevity and because others have explained it way better than I can), you'll need to use the following code to make your program work:

```
public partial class formSouthPark : Form
{
    public formSouthPark()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // These variables need to be declared outside both function scopes.
    int originalHeight;
    int originalWidth;

    public void formSouthPark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Snow;
        originalHeight = pictureEric.Height;
        originalWidth = pictureEric.Width;
    }

    private void buttonRestoreEric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureEric.Height = originalHeight;
        pictureEric.Width = originalWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was kind of dumb of me because I had done something like this before. Sorry to bother you with the stupid question :)

Comment: @WimNaudts Please click the check mark next to this answer if it helped to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Your global variables are not global.

Change

public void formSouthPark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Snow;
    int originalHeight = pictureEric.Height;
    int originalWidth = pictureEric.Width;
}
```

to

int originalHeight;
int originalWidth;

public void formSouthPark_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Snow;
    originalHeight = pictureEric.Height;
    originalWidth = pictureEric.Width;
}
```

Comment: @Ming Slogar answered this below.